# Pygame returning locking error during blitting

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a 2D game in pygame, and have a camera class that has a surface attribute, and each time the cameras get updated their surface is updated. All graphics are blitted to game.worldSurface, and then the main camera take a picture of that and blits it to the display surface. However, when using other cameras, i am unable to blit to the worldsurface and get a locking error. i have tried .unlock(). what could be causing this?

```
import pygame
import pickle
class Tileset:
    def __init__(self, location):
        pass

class Tilemap:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Collisionmap(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, spritesheet):
        super().__init__()
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(spritesheet)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.spritesheet, (self.x, self.y))

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Camera:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
    def moveToSprite(self, sprite):
        self.x = sprite.rect.centerx - WIDTH // 2
        self.y = sprite.rect.centery - HEIGHT // 2
    def update(self, world):
        self.surface = world.subsurface((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

class Level:
    def __init__(self, terrarin, collision, mobs):
        self.terrain = terrain
        self.collision = collision
        self.mobs = mobs

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
        self.mainCamera = Camera()
        self.mainCamera.width = self.DISPLAYSURF.get_width()
        self.mainCamera.height = self.DISPLAYSURF.get_height()
        self.otherCameras = []
        self.worldSurface = pygame.Surface((10000, 10000))
        self.player = Player("marioSS.jpg")
        self.otherCameras.append(Camera())
        self.run()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                pass
            self.earlyUpdate()
            self.update()
            self.lateUpdate()
            self.graphicsUpdate()
    def update(self):
        pass
    def earlyUpdate(self):
        pass
    def lateUpdate(self):
        pass
    def graphicsUpdate(self):
        for each in self.otherCameras:
            each.update(self.worldSurface)
        self.player.draw(self.worldSurface)
        self.otherCameras[0].surface.unlock()
        self.worldSurface.unlock()
        self.worldSurface.blit(self.otherCameras[0].surface, (100, 100)) ##Error here
        self.mainCamera.update(self.worldSurface)
        self.DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.mainCamera.surface, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()

x = Game()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem makes `world.subsurface()` in `Camera.update()`

It doesn't copy data from `world` to `surface` but it assigns access to original `world`. And later you have: `camera.surface` keeps access to `world`, and `blit` try to copy from `camera.surface` to `world` - so finally it tries to copy from `world` to `world`. And maybe it locks it.

But if in `Camera.update()`  you use `.copy()`

```
self.surface = world.subsurface((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)).copy()
```

or blit it

```
self.surface.blit(world.subsurface((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)), (0,0))
```

then it works.

---

DOC: [subsurface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface)

> subsurface(Rect) -> Surface
>
> Returns a new Surface that **shares its pixels with its new parent.**